# What's the word, what's it for? How's it stored, what is yours?

Tags: riddle

> I begin on the fifth floor
> and end on floor ninety-nine.
> Made by rounds of four
> and bland bits of design.
>
> Here its value's its description
> advance of being digested.
> Some checks confused with encryption.
> Has your security been tested?

What's the word?
What's it for?
How's it stored?
What is yours?

Answer (score 2):

you are a

> 1. Hash algorithm
>  2. Used for checking validity without storing the original
>  3. Stored as one of the valid hash values (or buckets).
>  4. you want my name hashed? So it sounds like you are describing a hash algorithm that goes from 5 to 99, so adding up Ascii values of my name (SteveV) mod 94 +5 would do that, which is 83+116+101+118+101+86 mod 94 + 5 = 40

I begin on the fifth floor
and end on floor ninety-nine.

> When you hash something you put it the results in buckets or floors?

Made by rounds of four
and bland bits of design.

> This sounds like it may be describing a hash technique

Here its value's its description
advance of being digested.

> hash is food before it is eaten/digested

Some checks confused with encryption.
Has your security been tested?

> Hash is confused with encryption.  But encryption can be decrypted, hash is one way.

Oh and

> your anagram spells "I am a Hash"

Comment: Very close! I've added the four questions more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Are you a

> Password

I begin on the fifth floor
and end on floor ninety-nine.

> It can have 5 characters, but I an not sure about the 99

Made by rounds of four

> A metal lock can have 4 spinning number circles for the combination.

and bland bits of design.

> Some passwords can look like this if you type them in ******.

Here its value's its description
advance of being digested.

> They are codes that can be cracked.

Some checks confused with encryption.
Has your security been tested?

> You need to have a strong password.

Comment: Its good! but their are four questions... ok 3 serious ones. I'll clarify it in the question!

Comment: [Couldn't help it.](http://www.bash.org/?244321) Sorry.